# Variable name is getting added instead of its value , in javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable name getting added instead of its value, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386390/variable-name-getting-added-instead-of-its-value-javascript)

I have problem while adding values to JavaScript object, adding value is key,value pair
here is sample.

```
//JavaScript object

 var cart=new Object();
 function add()
 {
      var rating="1"
      var category="somecat";
      var user="user1";

       if(cart[user]==null)     
            cart[user]={category:rating};  
       else
             cart[user][category]=rating;
  }
```

What I was expecting was that if user exists in cart object then value for his particular should get replaced, and if user doesn't exists then new user and category should be added.

The code is working fine when user already exists. 
Problem is, when m adding a new element with `cart[user]={category:rating}` then its adding the variable name as key i.e. category , not the value inside it ("somecat").

Is there any way to do? using json or jquery or javascript itself?
Please help. thanks!

Is there any way to assign value inside the variable

Comment: Exact duplicate from a different user?