# Variable name getting added instead of its value, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem while adding values to a JavaScript object: the value to add is a `key,value` pair. Here is sample:

```
//JavaScript object

var cart=new Object();

function add()
{
  var rating="1"
  var category="somecat";
  var user="user1";

   if(cart[user]==null)

        cart[user]={category:rating};

   else

         cart[user][category]=rating;
 }
```

What I was expecting is that if `user` exists in cart object then value for his particular should get replaced, and if `user` doesn't exist then new user and category should be added.

The code is working fine when `user` already exists. Problem is, when I am adding a new element with `cart[user]={category:rating}` then its adding the variable name as key i.e. category , not the value inside it ("somecat").

Is there any way to do this using json, jquery or javascript itself?

Is there any way to assign value inside the variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to use a variable to define a property name inside object literal notation. It accepts identifiers or strings, but both identify property names, not variables.

You have to create the object then add the property:

```
if(!cart[user]) { 
   cart[user] = {};
}
cart[user][category] = rating;
```

Comment: Thanks ! :) means it treats everything as property name. (literal). that's nice to know . thanks

Comment: I have another query . cart[user]={category:rating}; in this case the value of rating is getting added i.e: "1" . how this?

Comment: Because that is a value, not a property name.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to replace

```
{category:rating}
```

with

```
var obj = {};
obj[category] = rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object literal the key must be a string, so in your code it will be "category".  If instead you do:

```
  var rating="1"
  var category="somecat";
  var user="user1";

   if( !cart[user] ) {     
        cart[user]={};  
   }

   cart[user][category]=rating;
```

That will initialise a non existing user to an empty object and then add the category.